# methods of getting Dart UTC dates

Tags: flutter, dart

does the following code

```
    int timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
    DateTime utcDate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp, isUtc: true);
```

Give the same output as the code below?

```
    final DateTime dateNow = DateTime.now().toUtc();
```

Comment: Yes, except that the millisecond version obviously will give you only millisecond resolution, whereas `DateTime.now().toUtc()` can give you microseconds.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they do.
You can check it on https://dartpad.dev with this code:

```
void main() {
   int timestamp = DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch;
   DateTime utcDate = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(timestamp, isUtc: true);
   print(utcDate);
   final DateTime dateNow = DateTime.now().toUtc();
   print(dateNow);
}
```

They are here not the same because the second runs after the first, but normally they are

Comment: Hi @His4545, How did it manage to return true in the first post you made?